# How to create a dynamic regex based on condition?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a password generator where I can tick options (letters / numbers / special characters)...

For each ticked input, I want to generate a different regex pattern that accept wider range of characters, with at least white spaces accepted :

```
const alpha = alphaInputEl.checked;
const numeric = numericInputEl.checked;
const special = specialInputEl.checked;

return new RegExp(`/[
  ${alpha ? "a-zA-Z " : " "}
  ${numeric ? "0-9" : ""}
  ${special ? "$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-" : ""}
]/`)
```

But I can't test against that regex. How can I build that regex dynamically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I removed the slashes to make it work.

Doc ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Working version:

```
return new RegExp(`[${alpha ? "a-z-A-Z " : " "}${numeric ? "0-9" : ""}${special ? "$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-" : ""}]`)
```